# Xcode5.1.1 and Xcode6 beta7 iOS7.1 64-bit [Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

```
[Allocator] Mapping failed %d
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
[Allocator] Allocator invalid, falling back to malloc
```

And my app crash!

Answer (score 11):

For me, this is an issue with Crashlytics when running a 64-bit Simulator. Crashlytics is aware of the problem and say they're working on it.

Comment: Oh! I am using Crashlytics! That's it! Thank you very much man! Thank you!

Comment: They just emailed me that its been fixed. Restart your Crashlytics app to get the update.

Comment: Does anyone know if they've fixed this issue?

Comment: Interesting. I just got this in iOS 8 when testing on my phone.